# How to helm upgrade with v3 and remove / overwrite any manual changes that have been applied to templates

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a problem where we essentially discovered a piece of stale configuration in a live environment on one of our deployments (a config map was added as a volume mount). Reading through the docs [here](https://v3.helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/) (search for 'Upgrades where live state has changed') we can see that helm v2 would purge changes that were introduced to a template via external actors. Whereas v3 is very clever and will merge externally introduced changes alongside template changes as long as they dont conflict.

So how do we in helm v3 run a upgrade that purges any manual template changes that may have been introduced?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, the `--force` flag should do the trick.

`--force       force resource updates through a replacement strategy`

However, there are some issues with it as mentioned in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/9433).